# ushare for sharing between kodi on ubunrtu 16.04 und Lg smart tv webos 2.x

Tags: kodi, ushare

Can/must I install uShare to share/stream Kodi on my LG Smart tv WebOs 2.x.
Please give me some advice if I'm wrong in the approach of this task?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share multimedia files the easiest approach is to install minidlna.

```
sudo apt-get install minidlna
```

Then edit the minidlna.conf file with

gksu gedit /etc/minidlna.conf

Add shares for video, pictures and audio. The configuration file is well commented.

Restart the service with

```
sudo service minidlna restart
```

You should be able to see the new input on your LG TV.

Comment: Solved my problem, thank you!